# my Button in react dosen't work - I use useState and useEffect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am not sure why my Button dosen't work, I use useState and useEffect

here is my code:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    // import Timeout from "await-timeout";
    import axios from "axios";
    
    export default function Dogs() {
      const [dog, set_Dog] = useState(" ");
      console.log({ dog });
    
      useEffect(() => {
        async function getFetch() {
          const res = await axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
          const {
            data: { message },
          } = res;
          console.log("Got back", message);
          set_Dog(message);
        }
        getFetch();
      }, []);
    
      function output() {
        set_Dog(dog);
        // console.log(set_Dog({ dog }));
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>If you like Dogs,{dog} Press Button</h2>
          <button onClick={output}>Click me</button>
          {dog}
          <img src={dog} />
        </div>
      );
    }`
```

when I click on the button the image be disappeared, I want to show a new image of the dog without refresh my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `dog` which is being set on the in the function `output` never changes because of **stale closure**.

Because you want to populate the state on `mount` and also change it when user clicks on a button, you have to create the function which calls the API in the function scope and memoize it with `useCallback`, the same function can be passed to the `onClick`. For example,

```js
export default function Dogs() {
  const [dog, set_Dog] = useState("");
  console.log({ dog });

  const getDogPic = useCallback(async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
    const {
      data: { message }
    } = res;
    console.log("Got back", message);
    set_Dog(message);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getDogPic();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>If you like Dogs,{dog} Press Button</h2>
      <button onClick={getDogPic}>Click me</button>
      {dog}
      <img src={dog} alt={"dog-pic"} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-browser-x88pi?file=/src/index.js)

Read more about [stale-closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **useRef** to keep a reference to your function after fetching the first image.

```
const click_ref = React.useRef(null);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getFetch() {
      const res = await axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
      const {
        data: { message },
      } = res;
      console.log("Got back", message);
      set_Dog(message);
    }
    getFetch();
    click_ref.current = getFetch;
  }, []);
```

```
<button onClick={() => click_ref.current()}>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :
`onClick={() => output()}`

Like that it only renders when you clicking on the button and not everytime the component re-render.